# Stuck in boot loop due to wrong repartition

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, twrp, boot-loop, odin

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 GT-I9300 and I use it for developing tests. Long ago, it stopped working and I had to restart it, but it was showing just the samsung logo and animation. Sometimes it could be turned on and happened again.

I tried to install a new system in order to fix it; so I chose LineageOS but it needs TWRP. I used ODIN to flash TWRP but each time the Odin log shows get pit for mapping.

I searched everywhere for a solution. Later I found a solution to flash using a PIT file. My mistake was that I tried to flash TWRP with a wrong PIT file. But that failed.

Now whenever I turn on my device, it just shows the Samsung logo (no animation) and flickers. No boot, no recovery, and just download mode. How can I solve it?

Comment: restore stock with Odin